# openvino on macOS build issue

Tags: c++, macos, g++, openvino, inference-engine

I followed the instruction on thier github https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino to build it on macOS, done it and when i wrote a small code to check was all clear or not

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fstream>

#define USE_STATIC_IE

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <ie_core.hpp>

using namespace :: std;

int main(){
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/inference-engine/temp/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libngraph.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libinference_engine_transformations.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libinference_engine_legacy.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libinference_engine.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libinference_engine_lp_transformations.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlopen("/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/libMKLDNNPlugin.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);

    const std::string pluginsFilePath = "/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib/plugins.xml";
    InferenceEngine::Core ie(pluginsFilePath);
    const auto info = ie.GetVersions("CPU");

    if(!info.empty())
        cout << "Yes";

    return 0;
}
```

when i compile it with command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/inference-engine/include testdll.cpp -o testdll && "/Users/nk/Documents/FelenaSoft/"testdll
```

it gave me the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "InferenceEngine::Core::Core(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in testdll-788073.o
  "InferenceEngine::Core::GetVersions(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      _main in testdll-788073.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

then i added .a libs and ran this command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -L/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/bin/intel64/Release/lib -lmkldnn -lpugixml -linference_engine_s -I/Users/nk/Documents/HZ/openvino/inference-engine/include testdll.cpp -o testdll && "/Users/nk/Documents/FelenaSoft/"testdll
```

and i got this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ngraph::as_output_vector(std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node> > > const&)", referenced from:
      ngraph::Node::generate_adjoints(ngraph::autodiff::Adjoints&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node> > > const&) in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::match_node(ngraph::pattern::Matcher*, ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::match_value(ngraph::pattern::Matcher*, ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> const&, ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::constant_fold(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > >&, std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::set_arguments(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&)", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::clone_with_new_inputs(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::set_output_type(unsigned long, ngraph::element::Type const&, ngraph::PartialShape const&)", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::clone_with_new_inputs(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::m_next_instance_id", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode> std::__1::shared_ptr<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode>::make_shared<>() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::validate_and_infer_types()", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::evaluate(std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::runtime::HostTensor>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::runtime::HostTensor> > > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::runtime::HostTensor>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::runtime::HostTensor> > > const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::~Node()", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::~ExecutionNode() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::~ExecutionNode() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
      std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode, std::__1::allocator<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
      std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode, std::__1::allocator<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::is_dynamic() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::description() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::is_constant() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_arguments() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_output_size() const", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::clone_with_new_inputs(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::write_description(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::copy_with_new_args(std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_output_element_type(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::clone_with_new_inputs(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_default_output_index() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_output_partial_shape(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode::clone_with_new_inputs(std::__1::vector<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node>, std::__1::allocator<ngraph::Output<ngraph::Node> > > const&) const in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::get_autob() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "ngraph::Node::is_output() const", referenced from:
      vtable for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for ngraph::Node", referenced from:
      typeinfo for ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  "vtable for ngraph::Node", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode> std::__1::shared_ptr<ExecGraphInfoSerialization::ExecutionNode>::make_shared<>() in libinference_engine_s.a(ie_rtti.cpp.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did anyone had the same problem as me, and did anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost just need to cross check with you on your toolkit installation. Since you are trying to run a model already, I assume you already set it up properly as in (fyi latest version is 2020.4): https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_macos.html

The error that you are getting, the Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 is an Xcode build failure indicating you missed out something in your inference engine or the way you link the model with certain resources are incorrect or some other reasons. As long as this error persist you won't be able to compile your code. That is why you got the linker command failed with exit code 1.

Most error occurs because the users did not Set the OpenVINO environment variables or Configure the Model Optimizer correctly. This is why it's really important to Run verification scripts to verify installation and compile samples.

Before running any **custom model**, it is good to have a solid working Openvino environment, hence  please help to check whether you could run the default models as in example here https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_macos.html

By default, **you should already have pre-trained models** including open zoo model, Model Optimizer and Inference Engine which are **working example** to work with **if you configured the toolkit correctly**. These should already located in your installed toolkit's directory which you don't have to install separately from other resources.

Please take a note that you need:
**CMake 3.4 or higher,
Python 3.5 or higher,
Apple Xcode* Command Line Tools**,
(Optional) Apple Xcode* IDE (not required for OpenVINO, but useful for development),

And supported MAC OS is **macOS* 10.14.4**

Again, please help to cross check what you have in your Openvino environment and steps you had used to configure with the official documentation https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_macos.html

Thanks!